# Generic Interface with Type T and where

Tags: c#, generics

I try my first steps into generic interfaces and have this interface:

```
public interface ISetting<T>
{
    T Value { get; }
}
```

And a implementation like this:

```
public class MySetting : ISetting<DateTime> 
{ 
    DateTime Value { get; }
}
```

Now my target is, that I can write my code like this in my service layer:

```
public class MyService
{
    public DateTime GetMySetting()
    {
        return MyDataLayer.GetSettings<MySetting>();
    }
}
```

So in my DataLayer i am struggling with my implementation of my generic and where:

```
public T ReadOrAddOne<T>() where T : ISetting<????>
{
    // My Code goes here
}
```

So how to tell my ISetting which Type I am awaiting?

Comment: What kind of code you expect in "// My Code goes here" - you can't new up `ISetting<T>` based on just type... So how your `ReadOrAddOne` is going to get that? (Which may open up more options - right now only `ReadOrAddOne<T,R>` is sensible as shown in Rawitas Krungkaew answer)

Comment: Yes I can :) 
I allready have that when I do it like where ISetting<T>, new(), So I can create a new instance

Comment: But you can't define two types with one parameter - so if you stick with one type parameter you either don't know return type of `Value` or concrete type of `ISetting<T>`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to define another letter to represent that type.

```
public T ReadOrAddOne<T,R>() where T : ISetting<R>
{
    return default(T);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `where R : ISetting<T>` ?

Comment: Yeah, I had that allready, but then my calling code is not 

        return MyDataLayer.GetSettings<MySetting>();

if would be 

        return MyDataLayer.GetSettings<MySetting, DateTime>(); right?

Comment: @Kovu indeed. There is no way for compiler to find out which of many `ISettings<...>` your class potentially implements to pick as result - so you need both parameters - actual class implementing the interface and interface itself...

Comment: @Kovu You mean both of them have the same type?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: THank you, I was just asking to avoid that =/